# Print sas datatset having 100,000 columns in to excel file

Tags: sas

I need to print a sas dataset having 100,000 rows * 100,000 columns into excel file.
Proc export or ODS html statements are breaking and hence, are unable to print the same.

Data in file statements are able to print the same. But, due to their logical record length limit, the printing is not proper and essentially my one row is being broken down into 3 rows.
Is there a way out or is this a limitation of SAS in terms of data handling?

Comment: And once this gigantic data set is in excel, what will you do with it?!

Comment: but even the tab or comma delimited text file is doing the same....as far as i know, text files shouldn't have any such limitations

Comment: i need to to test my matrix factorization logic.........

Comment: my problem statement may be accessed at: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277434/edited-pythonnumpy-1-d-to-2-d-and-vice-versa-for

Comment: I looked at the problem description in the above link - I'm pretty sure you are going about this the wrong way. You need to take a look a sparse matrix representation - there are plenty of algorithms which will work fine even if you do not input a dense matrix ( which is what I suspect you are trying to do with your 100000*100000 matrix).

Comment: Text files may have limitations depending on the OS.  SAS does not enforce any particular limitations beyond that of the OS.

Answer (score 6):

Not so much a limitation of SAS, but a limitation of Excel, which can handle up to 16384 columns and up to ~1 million rows, depending on the version. Excel isn't meant to handle datasets of this magnitude; use a proper database.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly cannot get this into excel in any system.

You should be able to get this into another format, like a text file.  For example:

```
data mydata;
array vars[100000];
do _n_=1 to 10;
 do _t = 1 to dim(vars);
  vars[_t]=_t;
 end;
 output;
end;
drop _t;
run;

data _null_;
file "c:\temp\myfile.csv" dlm=',' lrecl=2000000;
set mydata;
put _all_;
run;
```

*put *all* doesn't really work properly for this, but as I don't know your variable names or setup I cannot really give you a better solution; more than likely you can use a shortcut to define the put statement.;

Maximum LRECL value depends on your operating system, but I'd think most of them could handle a million or two.  Certainly Win7 can.  You could also use PROC EXPORT to a csv, but you'd have to grab the (300k lines of) code from the log and modify the LRECL to be larger as it defaults to 32767, and I don't think you can modify it in the proc.

SAS/IML would also allow another option.  I'm not sure you could really do 100k*100k on any reasonable system (if it's numeric 8 byte matrix elements, you're at 80 billion bytes required to store...)

```
proc iml;
x=j(1e5,1e5,12345);

filename out ’c:\temp\myfile.csv’;
file out lrecl=800000;
do i=1 to nrow(x);
  do j=1 to ncol(x);
   put (x[i,j]) 5.0 +5 ',' @;
  end;
put;
end;
closefile out;
quit;
```

Edit: It seems that the lrecl statement in IML doesn't quite behave properly, or else I'm doing something wrong here - but that may be a fault of my system.  I get buffer overflows even when the lrecl is clearly long enough.